# Запрос по выдаче последних 5 записей с первыми 5 предложениями

Tags: php, mysql

Как сформировать запрос к БД, чтобы он выдал только последние 5 записей и в каждой записи было по первых 5 предложений?
Структура БД

```
CREATE TABLE news (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  nazv varchar(27) DEFAULT NULL,
  text text,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY id (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5  *//выведет последнии 5 записей*
```

А вот по 5 предложений я не знаю, как правильно, я делал у себя деревянным способом: просто вывести 300 знаков с поля text. Допустим, выполнил запрос:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5";
 $resultat = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());;
 $s = mysql_fetch_array($res);
 $rest = substr($s[text], 0, 300);
```

Теперь $rest показывает только первые 300 знаков. Ну можете там, когда будете выводить, добавить еще многоточие, например:

```
//выводим текст
<бла-бла-бла>".$rest." ... <бла-бла-бла>
```

Comment: Может быть количество точек считать?

Comment: Можно и так, например, скопировать с первого символа до тех пор пока не встретит 5 точку (ну, в смысле символ, а не действительно 5 точку :D ). Я брал всю информацию при работе по строке отсюда - http://php.su/functions/?cat=strings

Comment: Спасибо за юмор и за совет!